# Terminal error in mac

Tags: macos, bash

I used to do something to change the looking my of macbook terminal(adding color to character, etc). However, since than, when ever I try "ls", it always gave the error like:

```
error : invalid character '' in LSCOLORS env var.
```

How to set up my env to fix it please?

Update: I fixed the problem by fix my .bash_profile in changing to

```
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

Comment: it'd be helpful if you showed us exactly what you changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figure out your current setting - run 'grep "LSCOLORS=" ~/.bash_profile'

open your ~.bash_profile, find the LSCOLORS definition. Change it as follows:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have added a line beginning with LSCOLORS= some character to your .bash_profile. Open it in terminal with nano ~/.bash_profile or using TextEdit and remove that line.